# order by created_at of associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm making a very bare bones forum with Rails (more for the experience than actually producing production ready code), and I'm wondering how to implement a common feature.

In the index of topics_controller, if I do the following, the most recent topic will be located at the top of the topics list.

topics_controller.rb

```
def index

@topics = Topic.all.order("created_at DESC")

end
```

However, I wish to have the topics ordered by their most recent posts.  When a user creates a new topic, they are required to create the first post for that topic, so if I can figure out how to order topics by the most recently created post, then that would solve every thing. For example, a topic created yesterday ('yesterday's topic') might still be placed above a topic created today ('todays topic') if 'yesterday's topic' had a new post added to it just a moment ago.

In the models,

```
Topic.rb
has_many :posts

Post.rb

belongs_to :topic
```

Note, I'm sure there's a way to do this in Rails, but as I'm sure it's faster to do the ordering in the database, I'm wondering if there's a way to do the ordering in the database. However, if you only know the Rails solution that'd be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your association to

```
belongs_to :topic, touch: true
```

Then every new post will update the `updated_at` of the associated topic.

> Quote from the [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-touch):
>
> If you set the `:touch` option to `true`, then the `updated_at` or `updated_on` timestamp on the associated object will be set to the current time whenever this object is saved or destroyed.

Comment: Thanks. that's easy. However, just to be clear for anyone reading this answer, I'm now ordering by updated at `@topics = Topic.all.order("updated_at DESC")`

Comment: This is really a pretty bad way to go about this. Any time a topic gets updated, for example renaming it, it will pop up to the top of the list.

Comment: To the downvoter: I agree that this leads to updates on parent objects and that might have an impact on the apps performance. *BUT*: This is recommended by the [Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#russian-doll-caching) and it is essential when you want to use the russian doll caching strategy.

Answer (score 0):

As topics seems to be less editable and mostly readable, it would be easier to add touch: true to the post -> topic association. In that scenario rails will change updated_at on every topic that gets a new post. After that just use Topic.order(updated_at: :desc) to get recents - yesterday’s topics with fresh today’s comments would be ahead of today’s topic that where made before those comments. 
Another way of doing this - Joining posts to topics, grouping and ordering by max post created at. It would be slower though. 
Also, do not forget pagination - Topic.all isn’t quite a good thing, probably you know this but just in case